How to export internal runtime functions using go:linkname to bypass linkname checks in Go 1.23?
I would like to ask everyone for your help. In external code, I used //go:linkname directive as follows:
//go:linkname runtime_setEventErr runtime.(*pollDesc).setEventErr
func runtime_setEventErr(pd runtimePollDesc, b bool, seq uintptr)

The runtime.(*pollDesc).setEventErr function has been linked using linkname. It works well before go1.23, but since go1.23 lock down future uses of linkname, it can't work. I want to export this function within a private go runtime to remove the linkname check. How should I modify it? I have tried several ways but none of them seem to work:
//go:linkname setEventErr
func (pd *pollDesc) setEventErr(b bool, seq uintptr)

//go:linkname (*pollDesc).setEventErr
func (pd *pollDesc) setEventErr(b bool, seq uintptr)

//go:linkname runtime.(*pollDesc).setEventErr
func (pd *pollDesc) setEventErr(b bool, seq uintptr)

cd go/src && ./make.bash

The error log is:
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:178:3: //go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable


go linkname line is syntactically correct. i see few issues here: 1. the first argument to runtime_setEventErr should be a pointer of pollDesc ie. *runtime. pollDesc 2. but you can not access the private type of runtime (runtime.pollDesc) from another package

The short answer is you can't this is designed on purpose see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/67401.
The long answer is that you can use the -ldflags=-checklinkname=0 flag like this go build -ldflags=-checklinkname=0 . which disable the check while building (also work for go run, go install, go test, ...) however you should take a read at #67401 first and understand why this has been disallowed before taking this risk.
